# Prevent Popup from QZ Tray on online server

Tags: javascript, openssl, qz-tray

I am writing script for woocommerce **offline POS ordering** where **QZ Tray** can help for print from local PC.

I have manage to integrate it but dialog box comes says,

> Wants to connect QZ Tray Untrusted webiste

To avoid that i have done some research.

What i understood is there is a private key required like SSL.
as explained here, https://github.com/qzind/tray/blob/2.0/assets/signing/sign-message.js

i tried the same as above but it wont work on local host, may be due to fact that, as i didn't created SSL yet.

But can it be achieved **for server SSL?** i mean if i write my domain private key as below and pass it to function **qz.security.setSignaturePromise**

```
 var privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
   "MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQC0z9FeMynsC8+u\n" +
   "dvX+LciZxnh5uRj4C9S6tNeeAlIGCfQYk0zUcNFCoCkTknNQd/YEiawDLNbxBqut\n" +
   "bMDZ1aarys1a0lYmUeVLCIqvzBkPJTSQsCopQQ9V8WuT252zzNzs68dVGNdCJd5J\n" +
   "NRQykpwexmnjPPv0mvj7i8XgG379TyW6P+WWV5okeUkXJ9eJS2ouDYdR2SM9BoVW\n" +
   "+FgxDu6BmXhozW5EfsnajFp7HL8kQClI0QOc79yuKl3492rH6bzFsFn2lfwWy9ic\n" +
   "7cP8EpCTeFp1tFaD+vxBhPZkeTQ1HKx6hQ5zeHIB5ySJJZ7af2W8r4eTGYzbdRW2\n" +
   "4DDHCPhZAgMBAAECggEATvofR3gtrY8TLe+ET3wMDS8l3HU/NMlmKA9pxvjYfw7F\n" +
   "8h4VBw4oOWPfzU7A07syWJUR72kckbcKMfw42G18GbnBrRQG0UIgV3/ppBQQNg9Y\n" +
   "QILSR6bFXhLPnIvm/GxVa58pOEBbdec4it2Gbvie/MpJ4hn3K8atTqKk0djwxQ+b\n" +
   "QNBWtVgTkyIqMpUTFDi5ECiVXaGWZ5AOVK2TzlLRNQ5Y7US8lmGxVWzt0GONjXSE\n" +
   "iO/eBk8A7wI3zknMx5o1uZa/hFCPQH33uKeuqU5rmphi3zS0BY7iGY9EoKu/o+BO\n" +
   "HPwLQJ3wCDA3O9APZ3gmmbHFPMFPr/mVGeAeGP/BAQKBgQDaPELRriUaanWrZpgT\n" +
   "VnKKrRSqPED3anAVgmDfzTQwuR/3oD506F3AMBzloAo3y9BXmDfe8qLn6kgdZQKy\n" +
   "SFNLz888at96oi+2mEKPpvssqiwE6F3OtEM6yv4DP9KJHaHmXaWv+/sjwjzpFNjs\n" +
   "wGThBxFvrTWRJqBYsM1XNJJ2EQKBgQDUGbTSwHKqRCYWhQ1GPCZKE98l5UtMKvUb\n" +
   "hyWWOXoyoeYbJEMfG1ynX4JeXIkl6YtBjYCqszv9PjHa1rowTZaAPJ0V70zyhTcF\n" +
   "t581ii9LpiejIGrELHvJnW87QmjjStkjwGIqgKLp7Qe6CDjHI9HP1NM0uav/IQLW\n" +
   "pB6wyEz1yQKBgQCuxPut+Ax2rzM05KB9PAnWzO1zt3U/rtm8IAF8uVVGf7r+EDJ0\n" +
   "ZXJO6zj5G8WTEYHz5E86GI4ltBW0lKQoKouqdu27sMrv5trXG/CSImOcTVubQot9\n" +
   "chc1CkOKTp5IeJajafO6j817wZ4N+0gNsbYYEBUCnm/7ojdfT5ficpOoQQKBgQDB\n" +
   "PgKPmaNfGeQR1Ht5qEfCakR/RF/ML79Nq15FdmytQPBjfjBhYQ6Tt+MRkgGqtxOX\n" +
   "UBMQc2iOnGHT3puYcrhScec1GufidhjhbqDxqMrag7HNYDWmMlk+IeA7/4+Mtp8L\n" +
   "gbZuvvCvbLQDfIYueaYpUuBzQ08/jZYGdVU4/+WOcQKBgAGUN0kIB6EM1K/iZ0TN\n" +
   "jlt8P5UEV3ZCyATWFiGZRhhE2WAh8gv1jx4J26pcUs1n8sd2a1h6ZuBSqsyIlNSp\n" +
   "xtKsm3bqQFDHRrPcsBX4nanrw9DzkpH1k/I3WMSdGqkDAR3DtL7yXTJXJo2Sbrp5\n" +
   "EjzSn7DcDE1tL2En/tSVXeUY\n" +
   "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
```

Can any one guide me can i use that?

Comment: @tresf can you help me in it sir!

Comment: does localhost key works, as SSL for localhost can be created as guided here. https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-get-https-working-in-windows-10-localhost-dev-environment @qz-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key can be created manually (like SSL, as you've stated), but with newer QZ Tray versions, I would recommend that you allow the software to do this for you.

Please use **Advanced, Site Manager, "+", Create New**, then with the files you have been given, follow the appropriate signing tutorial https://qz.io/wiki/signing-examples.

Note, this will only work on that one workstation.

Comment: sir highly thankful, let me see and update all here for future references. @tresf

Comment: Note, for offline pages, I would strongly recommend the JavaScript tutorial.  We have a YouTube tutorial linked at that page which should get you up and running in a matter of minutes.

Comment: sure, i will review that tutorial first, hats off sir!

Comment: great tutorial sir! i have embeded that in my woocommerce POS :-) soon release video in multi language and share with you aswell @tresf